Grape vine identify disease
I would like to ask what could be the problem with my vine. The vine grows near the wall in central Europe and so far there has been no problem with it. This year, however, it started to dry from the top and on the leaves, and it seems to me that some disease has attacked it. Could I ask you for help identifying what the problem could be?


To me, it seems some parasite that is picking the leaves, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetranychus_urticae (I do not think it is the red spider mite, but just to give an idea).
